# 12.04 critical error when opening windows games

Tags: 12.04

I am new to Linux.

Running on an AMD 170ghz processor (NX2100?), 80 gb HD and 512MB memory with GeForce FX5200 video card (can't find linux driver for it).

Have loaded (w/Playonlinux & wine) Age of Empires I and Sid Meier's Pirates and Crown and Cutlass. When I select open or play it says:

`The program empires.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close`

C&C won't even come up. Same error for Pirates.

What have I done wrong? As a matter-of-fact I can't play ANY downloaded/installed games except what came with 12.04.

Keep in mind, I know nothing about code or sudo stuff unless it is spelled out.
Any help at all?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you HAVE to install your graphics card's drivers.

You can find the Linux drivers at Nvidia's [Linux Drivers page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html).

Some Windows games/programs may not be able to be run using Wine or playonlinux or any other compatibility layer.You should check the [Wine Site](http://winehq.org) to make sure if the games/programs you are about to install can run properly.

Here are the links of the 2 games you are trying to play:

[Command & Conquer](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=7440)

[Pirates](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2719&iTestingId=10464)

Both Games were tested in older releases(you are using the latest which is 12.04) so i they may not be playable.